# Transition not working when using Javascript to set opacity of a list item

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I have a list that appears line by line upon a mouse click. I am changing the opacity of each list item from 0 to 1, however I can't seem to get transition to work with it. Whenever I set the transition duration to 1s, it instead takes 1s for each list item to appear instead of fading smoothly from opacity 0 to opacity 1.

Here is my javascript:

```
let counter = 0;

document.addEventListener('click', () => {
  counter = counter + 1;
  document.querySelector(`#line-${counter}`).style.opacity = 1;
});
```

Here is my CSS:

```
  li {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
  }
```

Here is my HTML:

```
 <ul>
          <li class="text" id="line-1">line 1</li>
          <li class="text" id="line-2">line 2</li>
          <li class="text" id="line-3">line 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for...

JavaScript:

```js
let counter = 0;

document.addEventListener('click', () => {
  counter = counter + 1;
  document.querySelector(`#line-${counter}`).classList.add("fadeIn");
});
```

CSS:

```css
li {
  opacity: 0;
}

.fadeIn {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
}
```

This fades in each list item over 0.3 seconds for every click.